# How do I launch a flow when a new item is posted on SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-power-automate-desktop, microsoft-flow

How do I launch a flow when a new item is posted on SharePoint?

I want to write a flow such that when someone posts an article on SharePoint, a predetermined set of persons are emailed that it has been done.

Can someone give me some advice on how to accomplish this? I think the solution should be direct and obvious to those well-versed in Microsoft Automation.
I thought I would ask around. I have some experience experimenting with Flows and Microsoft Automate. So I think I can follow directions.

Comment: You need to create a trigger for the workflow. Just read the documentation.